# Dialog activity to wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout

There have been similar questions to this related to dialog activities and how to make these full screen, but I have a slightly different problem. I want these dialogs to wrap the activity content.

Now, the "dialog activities" all inherit the following theme,

```
<style name="tabDialog" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

Example of activity definition in manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".TabSettingsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/tabDialog" android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" />
```

The content view parent view is defined like this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/dialog_rounded_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

and all the child views in the layout also specify wrap_content for both dimensions. I have tried using a RelativeLayout as the parent as well, but same same.

After the content view has been set in onCreate of the activity, I do this

```
  getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

None of these things actually seem to make any difference at all. The problem is mostly related to the dialog height, which is about 50% bigger than necessary. Half of the dialog is just dead space. Setting the root view dimensions to hardcoded dp units solves the problem, but this seems like a workaround rather than a solution.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Hy, did you managed to find a fix ?thanks

Comment: Are you using `Dialogue` as `Activity` or you are using `Activity` as `Dialogue`?  why?

Answer (score 3):

Try this out. This solved my problem.

```
<style name="NewDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Most of this code does not do anything (=> is already predefined in the parent style). The only thing you're changing is setting the background color to transparent and removing the title style (which doesn't seem to have any effect)

Answer (score 2):

The Dialog Background in parent view "dialog_rounded_background" you are using is the problem because it may be as larger as your screen size is. Please check that.

Answer (score 2):

use Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert theme instead .. it shall wrap the dialog height to wrap content.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the layout_margin.  If that fails then the regular activity padding and margins may be to blame.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a `DialogFragment` and it works well if you use `setStyle`

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public MyDialogFragment() {
            setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize customized dialog for same.

Simply set xml layout to fill in screen with parent `layout_width` to `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can get the width and height of android device screen By:

```
    //Define the size of layout 
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int widths = display.getWidth();  
    int heights = display.getHeight();
```

Then you can specify the width or height based on these values! As:

```
 getWindow().setLayout(widths ,
                       heights );
```

Hope this will be helpful :) ,,,